# How to increase width of the line numbers and code folding section in Atom.io

Tags: user-interface, atom-editor

I cannot see a code folding part properly and this is really annoying.
Is there a way to increase width of the section with line number and code folding arrow in Atom.io?

[cannot see code folding](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aCfUA.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would have to edit `styles.less` by going to File > Stylesheet and then adding the following code:

```
.gutter {
  margin-right: 1em;
}
```

This sets the distance between the gutter line number and the code to 1 em.

Comment: FYI: `em` is relative to the font-size of the `element` (so `1em` means 1 times the size of the current font)